# Can't match a string with 2-digit number at the end

Tags: awk, gawk

What the heck is wrong here:

```
else if ($i ~ /imm[0-9]+/) {
    CNT = match($i, /[0-9]+/)
    K = substr($i, CNT)
    n = int(K)
    print $i, "n = ", n, "CNT=", CNT, "K=", K
    for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++ ) { BITPATT = BITPATT " i" }
}
```

It finds smaller numbers (like imm1, imm3, imm5, imm8), but not if the number has 2 digits, like imm11. (Yes, awful code, but I'm a beginner) Tried /imm[0-9][0-9]/ and /imm[0-9]*/ and /imm[0-9]./, but no difference. I printed $i to see that the 'imm11' is there.

I couldn't get it to work even with 'else if ($i == "imm11") '.

Comment: If you post some sample input and expected output we can help you. Remember - a script that produces the output you expect from some input you provide is just the starting point for identifying a solution, it's not necessarily the right/best solution.

Comment: Well, the input is ARM Architecture Reference Manual, ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition converted to text form. I won't paste it here. Also my script is 136 lines long. The idea is to prepare table of thumb instructions with their bit patterns. The script is reducing the manual editing. There is then another script too, but it seems to work adequately well.

Comment: Ah, OK, I'll get back to you as soon as I find and study the ARM (whatever that is) documentation then. In the meantime, I'm sure if you put the tiniest bit of effort in you could some up with a small, simple example that just demonstrates this specific problem you're asking for help with. The latter may get you help faster...

Comment: The manual has 2736 pages. There are 499 ARM instructions and 522 thumb instructions. I already managed to sort out the ARM instructions (my 2 first ever awk scripts) and now I'm sorting out the thumb instructions - both 16- and 32-bit. ( http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first blush, the code seems to work (from bash)...

```
$ echo imm11 | awk 'BEGIN { i=0 } { if ($i ~ /imm[0-9]+/) { CNT = match($i, /[0-9]+/); K = substr($i, CNT); n = int(K); print $i, "n = ", n, "CNT=", CNT, "K=", K } }'
imm11 n =  11 CNT= 4 K= 11
```

I think there is something else going on earlier in your code to block this piece from executing.... maybe you need parentheses about the block before the else?

Comment: That works for me too - on command line. And weird that the code works with 'imm1' but not with 'imm11' or 'imm10'

Comment: Michael Back: You were right. This gets it, but I don't understand why it matches: $ echo imm11 | awk 'BEGIN { i=0 } { if ($i ~ /\(?1\)?/) { BITPATT = BITPATT " 1"; print $1; } }'
imm11

Comment: Ah, Now I understand. One shouldn't write code at 4AM. ;-)

Comment: That BEGIN section is doing nothing, get rid of it. Move the condition out of the action area and into the condition area. Don't use all upper case variable names to avoid clashing with builtins. The parens around `i` are doing nothing. The `+` in the match() is doing nothing. @turboscrew - What are you trying to do with the `(?` and `)?` in `/(?1)?/`?

Comment: The idea was to match "(" and ")"  and it looks like something ate the '\'s in front of them. Maybe the shell, It should have been "/\(?1\)?/. The 'i' is used as a loop counter within a 'while' going through the fields of the line - not shown here.

Comment: And the idea of '/imm[0-9]+/' was to find 'imm<n>' where <n> is a number with 1 or more digits.

Comment: Hi Ed, I initialize out of habit. If you remove the i=0 in the BEGIN section and use LINT = 1 with gawk, it will tell you that "i" was not initialized.  You can check with: gawk 'BEGIN {LINT=1; i++}'

Comment: @turboscrew - unless you are using the matching string, there is no need to use more than `/imm[0-9]/`.

Comment: Turboscrew, if the script is embedded in shell, /bin/sh might behave more like what you would expect. Also, the following might be more straightforward for the conversion... K=$(i); sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/, "", K); n = strtonum(K)

Comment: What I'm after is that there are a lot of different size 'imm's: imm2 imm3, imm5, imm6, ... imm10, imm11, imm12,... imm24. What I wanted to do is to replace imm<n> with n 'i's: imm4 -> i i i i

Comment: @Michael Back: I'm using bash, but I know what shell can do. (And I'm familiar with Bourne shell as well.)

Comment: This is what I'm getting now (some hand editing needed, but not too much): "1 1 1 1 0 S c c c c i i i i i i 1 0 j 0 J i i i i i i i i i i i "B<c>.W <label>". When I'm done editing, I read them into a LibreOffice Calc for further analysis and manipulation.

Comment: @terboscrew: How about... echo imm11 | awk -v i=0 'function rep(s, c, n,    i0, i) { if (n) { i0=0; if (s == "") { s=c; i0=1 }; for (i=i0; i<n; i++) s = s " " c; }; return s; }; $i ~ /imm/ { sub(/[[:alpha:]]+/, "", $i); bitpat = rep(bitpat, "i", ($i=="")?0:strtonum($i)); print bitpat }'  -- You will need to unroll it to make sense of it, but this creates a function to do the concatenation piece...  You can build on it to do what you want.  Try to put your parsing on the first level -- not in an if/else structure -- and see if it makes the logic more visible.